# Optimal weights for a linear combination

Tags: bayesian, genetics

I am trying to find optimal weights for a linear combination. I already know the signs of the weights (+/-).

Specifically I have gene expression data where 100 genes belong to a certain pathway. I know which genes are regulators or not (signs) for those 100 genes. I am trying to compute a pathway score for each sample using appropriate weights.

Is there any Bayesian type (so that I can use prior information +/-) approach that can be used to obtain weights?

Comment: Should these weights sum up to unity? (even though some of them will be negative)

Comment: actually i have no idea. seems like weights should sum to one.

Comment: What are the weights optimizing?

Comment: as long as reasonable, any objective function is fine.

Comment: *You* have to specify the objective, not us!  If you don't, your question is similar to asking "what's the value of $x+4$" without telling us what $x$ is... .

Comment: I see. i am sorry. actually I was thinking of maximizing the variance because i thought pca might be a possible solution. so i did some literature reviews on bayesian PCA, which i really didnt understand due to the limit of my knowledge.

Comment: If you can elaborate on "I am trying to compute a _pathway score_" -forget statistics for the moment, write about your discipline - and we may find a way to use statistics to help you. Is there a theoretical but unknown "pathway" (whatever that means),  that you try to approximate through the weighted combination of genes? Is there likewise some "pathway score" that exists but it is unknown and you try to uncover? Are you just trying to _describe_ something through this linear combination?